# On Account Owner change Contact owner is getting updated without any automation

Tags: account, contact, record-owner

Today I noticed in my salesforce org when i change Account Owner, All the related contact owners are changing automatically. I tried to search in whole org to find if any process is running behind to change but i found none.

I even tried it in another developer edition it is behaving the same.

Is this the expected behavior? Or did something recently changed in salesforce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With little more search i was able to find supporting docuemntation([https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_transfer.htm&type=5](http://Link)):

**Transfer of Associated Items**

When you change record ownership, **some associated items that are owned by the current record owner are also transferred to the new owner**.

**Record    Associated items that are also transferred**

Accounts    Contacts (on business accounts only), attachments, notes, open activities, open opportunities owned by the current account owner, and optionally, closed opportunities and open opportunities owned by other users.
Leads   Open activities. When transferring leads to a queue, open activities are not transferred.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is expected behavior.

Changing the Account owner automatically changes the Contact owner.

Same principle applies to changing the Case owner, if case has tasks then Task's `assigned to` will get changed.

If you dont want to change the contact owner based on account ownership then you need to write a trigger to handle this.

Comment: I see many questions in developer forums on how to update contact owner when Account owner changes and most people suggested to use triggers. Is the automated process released pretty recently.

Comment: No, this was there earlier

Comment: Note this [Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000XrJFAA0) and [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=account_owner_transfer.htm&type=5) is silent on this score but [feat exists as of Spring 17 in Financial Services Cloud](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring17/release-notes/rn_fsc_account_contact_sync.htm)